# How to get a valid access token to query search result from Facebook graph API

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I want to collect all the Facebook link from Facebook search function. What I'm using here is the Facebook graph API tool.
If I want to query the data for a keyword, for example: "limited";
I will use the URL:
`https://graph.facebook.com/v11.0/search?q=limited&access_token={my_access_token}`

[My image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yftSe.png)

However, I got the result as in the image. When I tried to create a workplace app and tried to get the access token of that app, I got the message as in the second image.

[Error message when getting the access token of a workplace app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/igrHb.png)

What I need now is an access token that has the permission to retrieve the data from the Facebook search. After that, I can use python to handle the rest.
Please help me out, thank you very much!

Comment: This functionality is not available for normal 3rd-party apps outside of the “Workplace” environment any more.

Comment: Thank you for that. May I ask you which tool should I use to scrape the search results from facebook search? I was using selenium and it worked well, however my boss want me to use this facebook-graph-api. Thank you very much!

Comment: You shouldn’t use any, because scraping is not allowed.